# Separating joined columns with awk

Tags: bash, vim, awk

I have a data file which looks like the following:

```
0.00000-130250.92921  28880.20200-159131.13121    301.58706
0.05000-130250.73120  28156.69202-158407.42322    294.03167
0.10000-130250.79137  28237.16138-158487.95275    294.87198
0.15000-130250.81209  28168.63042-158419.44250    294.15634
0.20000-130250.82418  28149.57611-158400.40029    293.95736
0.25000-130250.88438  28069.57135-158320.45573    293.12189
0.30000-130251.06059  28071.30576-158322.36635    293.14000
0.35000-130250.96639  28084.46351-158335.42990    293.27741
```

as you can see some of the columns which start with "-" sign are
joined to the previous one, for instance: 0.35000-130250.96639 
this should be 0.35000  and -130250.96639. I can separate the 
columns with VIM but I wanted to know if it is possible to do that
with AWK.

Thanks.

Comment: `awk -F- '{$1=$1}1' file` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sed`: replace each `-` with a space and `-`:

```
sed -e 's/-/ -/g' input > output
```

The `/g` means globally, i.e. it replaces all occurrences on each line, not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Using just `awk`

```
awk '{ gsub("-"," -") ; print }'
```