# How to separate column using character length with AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data, which is not formatted according to proper field separator (which is awk good at). But, what I know is, the data is fixed width.

```
 NODE     S1           S2           S3           SINT         SEQV    
   1  0.14919     -0.58396E-001-0.71230      0.86149      0.77873     
   2  0.56037E-001 0.23261E-002-0.37154      0.42757      0.40341     
   3  0.52036E-001 0.19762E-001-0.27222      0.32426      0.30939     
   4  0.59765E-001 0.22059E-001-0.24529      0.30505      0.28806     
   5  0.70704E-001-0.51976E-002-0.13862      0.20932      0.18354     
   6  0.11906      0.44607E-001-0.17493      0.29399      0.26474     
   7  0.25540      0.95993E-002-0.43110      0.68650      0.60246     
   8  0.52246E-001-0.47008E-001-0.35167      0.40391      0.36456     
   9  0.32215E-001-0.62291E-001-0.28800      0.32021      0.28497     
  10  0.28072E-001-0.68269E-001-0.28304      0.31111      0.27586     
  11  0.25990E-001-0.78663E-001-0.28626      0.31225      0.27527     
  12  0.26657E-001-0.79217E-001-0.29507      0.32173      0.28400
```

The expected output is something like this (the numbers in other columns can have format like in S2, in other parts of the data):

```
  NODE       S1           S2           S3           SINT         SEQV    
   1    0.14919       -0.58396E-001  -0.71230      0.86149      0.77873     
   2    0.56037E-001   0.23261E-002  -0.37154      0.42757      0.40341     
   3    0.52036E-001   0.19762E-001  -0.27222      0.32426      0.30939     
   4    0.59765E-001   0.22059E-001  -0.24529      0.30505      0.28806     
   5    0.70704E-001  -0.51976E-002  -0.13862      0.20932      0.18354     
   6    0.11906        0.44607E-001  -0.17493      0.29399      0.26474     
   7    0.25540        0.95993E-002  -0.43110      0.68650      0.60246     
   8    0.52246E-001  -0.47008E-001  -0.35167      0.40391      0.36456     
   9    0.32215E-001  -0.62291E-001  -0.28800      0.32021      0.28497     
  10    0.28072E-001  -0.68269E-001  -0.28304      0.31111      0.27586     
  11    0.25990E-001  -0.78663E-001  -0.28626      0.31225      0.27527     
  12    0.26657E-001  -0.79217E-001  -0.29507      0.32173      0.28400
```

The main problem is, sometimes the column are separated by space, sometime no space ('-' sign occupies the space), that is, no proper field separator. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955512/separating-joined-columns-with-awk), but  that data was consistent in terms of field separator. There might be two ways, according to my thinking,

1. Use character length. For example, starting from the second line, the characters are either 74 or 75 per line.
2. Use field width: Don't know if it's possible with AWK.

I'm new to AWK, I know it might be very easy with some other tools, but I would like to know if it's possible to separate/extract these columns using awk. I am using awk in terminal in MacOS.

Comment: Everything is possible with `awk` kindly post expected output too in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answers by [JNevill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill) & [Andriy Makukha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5407270/andriy-makukha) are fine in their own rights, I wanted to solve the problem specifically using NAWK (MacOS default AWK). I have found that "FIELDWIDTHS" is a gawk only feature [Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html),[machelp](https://www.mac-help.com/threads/awk.127138/).

The catch is to use

```
FS=""
```

which would consider each character as a field. As the fields are of equal width, it's possible to extract each column when one knows the number of characters in each column. For example, if I want to extract the first, second, third and the last column, I can use the following code (if the source data is named as: test_input.txt):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{print $1$2$3$4"\t"$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12$13$14$15$16$17$18"\t"$19$20$21$22$23$24$25$26$27$28$29$30$31"\t"$59$60$61$62$63$64$65$66$67$68$69$70}' test_input.txt
```

output:

```
NODE         S1             S2             SEQV    
   1      0.14919       -0.58396E-001   0.77873     
   2      0.56037E-001   0.23261E-002   0.40341     
   3      0.52036E-001   0.19762E-001   0.30939     
   4      0.59765E-001   0.22059E-001   0.28806     
   5      0.70704E-001  -0.51976E-002   0.18354     
   6      0.11906        0.44607E-001   0.26474     
   7      0.25540        0.95993E-002   0.60246     
   8      0.52246E-001  -0.47008E-001   0.36456     
   9      0.32215E-001  -0.62291E-001   0.28497     
  10      0.28072E-001  -0.68269E-001   0.27586     
  11      0.25990E-001  -0.78663E-001   0.27527     
  12      0.26657E-001  -0.79217E-001   0.28400
```

This is a simple but somewhat unsophisticated solution, but it works for me as of now, for large data. Any further refinement would be welcome...

Answer (score 4):

You can [split fields in a fixed width file in awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html) by specifying `FIELDWIDTHS` in your `BEGIN` block:

```
$ cat test
NODE     S1           S2           S3           SINT         SEQV
   1  0.14919     -0.58396E-001-0.71230      0.86149      0.77873
   2  0.56037E-001 0.23261E-002-0.37154      0.42757      0.40341
   3  0.52036E-001 0.19762E-001-0.27222      0.32426      0.30939
   4  0.59765E-001 0.22059E-001-0.24529      0.30505      0.28806
   5  0.70704E-001-0.51976E-002-0.13862      0.20932      0.18354
   6  0.11906      0.44607E-001-0.17493      0.29399      0.26474
   7  0.25540      0.95993E-002-0.43110      0.68650      0.60246
   8  0.52246E-001-0.47008E-001-0.35167      0.40391      0.36456
   9  0.32215E-001-0.62291E-001-0.28800      0.32021      0.28497
  10  0.28072E-001-0.68269E-001-0.28304      0.31111      0.27586
  11  0.25990E-001-0.78663E-001-0.28626      0.31225      0.27527
  12  0.26657E-001-0.79217E-001-0.29507      0.32173      0.28400

$ awk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS= "5 13 13 13 13"; OFS="|"}{$1=$1}1' test
NODE |    S1       |    S2       |    S3       |    SINT
   1 | 0.14919     |-0.58396E-001|-0.71230     | 0.86149
   2 | 0.56037E-001| 0.23261E-002|-0.37154     | 0.42757
   3 | 0.52036E-001| 0.19762E-001|-0.27222     | 0.32426
   4 | 0.59765E-001| 0.22059E-001|-0.24529     | 0.30505
   5 | 0.70704E-001|-0.51976E-002|-0.13862     | 0.20932
   6 | 0.11906     | 0.44607E-001|-0.17493     | 0.29399
   7 | 0.25540     | 0.95993E-002|-0.43110     | 0.68650
   8 | 0.52246E-001|-0.47008E-001|-0.35167     | 0.40391
   9 | 0.32215E-001|-0.62291E-001|-0.28800     | 0.32021
  10 | 0.28072E-001|-0.68269E-001|-0.28304     | 0.31111
  11 | 0.25990E-001|-0.78663E-001|-0.28626     | 0.31225
  12 | 0.26657E-001|-0.79217E-001|-0.29507     | 0.32173

$ awk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS= "5 13 13 13 13"; OFS="\t"}{$1=$1}1' test
NODE        S1              S2              S3              SINT
   1     0.14919        -0.58396E-001   -0.71230         0.86149
   2     0.56037E-001    0.23261E-002   -0.37154         0.42757
   3     0.52036E-001    0.19762E-001   -0.27222         0.32426
   4     0.59765E-001    0.22059E-001   -0.24529         0.30505
   5     0.70704E-001   -0.51976E-002   -0.13862         0.20932
   6     0.11906         0.44607E-001   -0.17493         0.29399
   7     0.25540         0.95993E-002   -0.43110         0.68650
   8     0.52246E-001   -0.47008E-001   -0.35167         0.40391
   9     0.32215E-001   -0.62291E-001   -0.28800         0.32021
  10     0.28072E-001   -0.68269E-001   -0.28304         0.31111
  11     0.25990E-001   -0.78663E-001   -0.28626         0.31225
  12     0.26657E-001   -0.79217E-001   -0.29507         0.32173
```

Probably have to tweak that a bit for whatever constitutes an actual field here, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: I've used several versions of awk and this works just fine.

Comment: Okay, I beg pardon. But it doesn't work with nawk version that comes with MacOS.

Comment: @SouravMandal That is a shame. I see [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/awk-nawk-gawk/) that it does appear to be missing from `nawk`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also parse your number format with regex and insert space before each number:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print; next } { print gensub(/(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?)/," \\1", "g") }' FILE
```

Output:

```
NODE     S1           S2           S3           SINT         SEQV    
    1   0.14919      -0.58396E-001 -0.71230       0.86149       0.77873     
    2   0.56037E-001  0.23261E-002 -0.37154       0.42757       0.40341     
    3   0.52036E-001  0.19762E-001 -0.27222       0.32426       0.30939     
    4   0.59765E-001  0.22059E-001 -0.24529       0.30505       0.28806     
    5   0.70704E-001 -0.51976E-002 -0.13862       0.20932       0.18354     
    6   0.11906       0.44607E-001 -0.17493       0.29399       0.26474     
    7   0.25540       0.95993E-002 -0.43110       0.68650       0.60246     
    8   0.52246E-001 -0.47008E-001 -0.35167       0.40391       0.36456     
    9   0.32215E-001 -0.62291E-001 -0.28800       0.32021       0.28497     
   10   0.28072E-001 -0.68269E-001 -0.28304       0.31111       0.27586     
   11   0.25990E-001 -0.78663E-001 -0.28626       0.31225       0.27527     
   12   0.26657E-001 -0.79217E-001 -0.29507       0.32173       0.28400
```

With this method you don't have to know the number of fields and field widths, therefore it can be more robust against data format changes.